# Getting HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden when i want to get account balance

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, infura, nethereum

Some months ago, I was able to get the balance of my account using this code (I run the code in Unity 2018 and get the code from tutorial in github. I modified some parts of the code). This is the link :https://gist.github.com/hafidkhoiruddin/992275be71f63bc5e9e8a9aac6339e2c, but since yesterday I can't get the balance. Would anybody help me? Here is the error :

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) Nethereum.JsonRpc.UnityClient.d__7:MoveNext() UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
>
> RW: Get Account Balance gave an exception : HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at E:/Unity-and-Ethereum-project-final - Copy/Assets/RW/Scripts/TestBalanceAnd Account Script/PlayerBalanceController.cs:87) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Comment: I don't know much about Nethereum but the snippets is using an old Infura URL. They changed that last year now you have to register with the site and obtain a token id to be able to make queries.

Comment: @Ismael yes i'm looking for the new URL of infura but did't found that can solve the problem